# Can I use the Neo4J browser with any other GraphDB?

Tags: neo4j

Is is possible to use the the Neo4J browser with other vendors (ex: use Neo4J with AgensGraph/Postgress)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, mainly due to the fact that protocols are not the same : `JDBC` vs `Bolt`.

Comment: I am learning these things, please excuse my ignorance, does cipher ride on top of these protocols? I thought it was common for both. Related to this is there an universal client ? One to rule them all :-)

Comment: We are all ignorant at a moment of time :) Cypher is the query language and yes both databases are using it. But the communication protocol (the pipe) between your client and the database is not the same. I'm not aware of a universal client. But to go from one to an other should not be hard in your code.

Comment: I am extremely interested in the easiness of rendering the query results as graphs. I have played with the Neo4j in their sandbox and it is amazing. If you are familiar with the others ..is there a match for this client? I am stuck with Postgress and can't figure out if the agensgraph browser is at least as good. Can't install it for the moment to see for myself

Answer (score 0):

@Minie,
You may use AgensBrowser for AgensGraph data. You may find the resource and support. https://bitnine.net/agensgraph-2-1-1-enterprise-linux/